# Events in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a `fadeTo` animation on a link that is into an Ember partial template;
this animation is activated on mouse click on the link and it is done like this:

```
jQuery('#object').fadeTo(1000, 1);
```

so it takes 1 second to complete; the thing is that if I move the mouse outside the partial template's area, before the animation finishes, then it stops;
for example if I click the link, the animation starts and the object starts to fade in, but if I move the mouse out of the partial template area before 1 second is passed, than the object will not be completely visible but its opacity will remain less then 1;

The function that executes the `fadeTo` code is called within `didInsertedElement` of the actual view...
Someone knows how can I have an animations that once started will complete even if the user moves the mouse outside the partial template area?

Comment: can you provide a working link that reproduces the issue ?

Comment: [link]http://www.importclimbingitalia.it/NUOVO/#/  You can see that clicking on the black phone icon (near the facebook link) the blob on the mainmenu disappears; then clicking again on a mainmenu item, the blob appears again, but if you move the mouse away from the mainmenu while it's appearing, than the animation stops; the mainmenu is a partial template in my ember app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Clicking on the link gives me a 404, and without more code it's tough to get context
2. Are you using Ember event handling properly?  You mentioned the `fadeTo` code was in the `didInsertElement` function, which doesn't sound right when handling a click event.  `didInsertElement` is a callback that is called after the element is rendered (or re-rendered).

Given the description, it sounds like you have two options.  Neither approach should be dependent on the cursor position.

#### Option 1

If your template is simple enough that you can bind to click events in your view, go for it.  That way, you don't have to specify any selectors (e.g., `#object`).

**In your template** you should just have a standard link:

```
    <a href="#"> link text </a>
```

Now, handle the event **in your view**

```
    App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({

      click: function(e) {
        $(e.target).fadeTo(1000, 1);
        return false;  // prevent page transition
      }

    });
```

#### Option 2

Bind to the link directly, and handle the event in your controller.

**In your template**, add an action to the link:

```
    <a href="#" id="object" {{action "fade"}}> link text </a>
```

Now, handle the event **in your controller** using the element id:

```
    App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

      actions: {
        fade: function() {
          $('#object').fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }
      }

   });
```

If I'm way off base here, please provide some code for us.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the link doesn't work anymore because i moved the site in the main directory; thank you for your explanation